# Add/Remove values from the textboxes in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I would like to add values from the input controls to the applicable divs as displayed in the picture
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylht6.png).
I followed this [Tutorial](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vqvaybbgxyj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-editor%2Fprofile-editor.component.html) and I am able to replicate the same controls again and again but not as represented in this picture. This is code, can someone lead me where I went wrong? posted the html and component.ts.

```
    <form [formGroup]="FemaForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-horizontal">
            <div formArrayName="aliases">
              <div *ngFor="let alias of aliases.controls; let i=index">
                   <label>Cause</label>
                      <input id="reason" formControlName="cause" type="text" class="form-control"
                        [formControlName]="i">
                   <label>Start</label>
                      <input name="Start" formControlName="Start" type="text" 
                        placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" [formControlName]="i" />
                   <label>End</label>                       
                     <input name="End" formControlName="End" type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"   [formControlName]="i" />    
                      <label >FLD</label>
                        <input id="FLD" formControlName="FLD" type="text" class="form-control"
                        [formControlName]="i" > 
                      <label>Valid </label>
                        <input id="Extn" formControlName="Extn" type="text" class="form-control"
                        [formControlName]="i">
                    <button (click)="deleteAlias(i)"></button>
                 </div>
              <button (click)="add(i)"> </button>
            <button type="submit">Log</button>
          </div>
      </form>

  export class TestComponent {        
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { } 

    FemaForm= this.fb.group({
         cause: [''],
         Start: [''],
         End: [''],
         FLD: [''],
         Extn: [''],    

       aliases: this.fb.array([
          this.fb.control('')
      ])
    });

  get aliases() {
  return this.FemaForm.get('aliases') as FormArray;
}
 add() {
  this.aliases.push(this.fb.control(''));
 }

    deleteAlias(index) {
     this.aliases.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```